# JPA: how to define complicated count without N+1 issue

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I need help in generating query in JPA.  Let's say I have these table

```
create table PERSON (
    person_id number(3,0) not null primary key,
    last_name varchar2(15) not null,
    first_name varchar2(15) not null,
    department varchar2(15) not null
);

create table PHONE (
    phone_id number(3,0) not null primary key,
    person_id number(3,0) not null,
    phone_type varchar2(10) not null,
    CONSTRAINT fk_person_id FOREIGN KEY (person_id)
    REFERENCES person (person_id)
);
```

I would like to define a query like:

```
select p1.person_id, p1.last_name, p1.first_name,
       (select count(1) from phone p2
        where p2.person_id = p1.person_id) as phone_count
from person p1;
```

My JPA class defined as below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PERSON")
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public class Person {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "PERSON_ID")
    private Integer personId;

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "DEPARTMENT")
    private String department;

    @OneToMany
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT) // or @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN) 
    @JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_ID", referencedColumnName="PERSON_ID")
    private Set<Phone> phones;

    .... getters and setters...
}


@Entity
@Table(name="PHONE")
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public class Person {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "PHONE_ID")
    private Integer phoneId;

    @Column(name = "PERSON_ID")
    private Integer personId;

    @Column(name = "PHONE_TYPE")
    private String phoneType;

    .... getters and setters ...
}
```

Since I have dynamic where clause, i.e last_name, first_name, department combination can be passed in as needed. I have a function:

```
personRepository.findAll(spec, pageable);
```

that helps me to solve the dynamic where clause and then I get the phone count via getPhones.size().  It works as expected. However, it creates N+1 issue.  If I have 500+ persons, it loops each person record and calls select query on phone table. My question is how to avoid N+1 issue in this case.

I am thinking to use native query as well and I don't know how to make the dynamic where clause work (my real program has more than 15 columns to filter). Help is appreciated.

Comment: Usually for normal query, I will simply suggest to add `from Person p left join fetch p.phones`.  Not familiar with usage of `Specification` though.  A quick check seems suggest that `Root` allow you to define `fetch` which in turns translate to a join fetch, for which is something you can do in constructing the specification

Comment: The @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN) will do the left join fetch, I assumed but it doesn't.  It still gave me N+1 query.

Comment: I almost never rely on eager fetch definition in entities, because 1. it does not always work, 2. I have no way to control.  I'd rather control fetching behavior in the query instead

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent JPA query would be:

```
SELECT
  p.personId, p.lastName, p.firstName,
  (SELECT COUNT(ph) FROM p.phones ph)
WHERE ...
```

This returns **tuples**, i.e. use it as:

```
TypedQuery<Object[]> q = em.createQuery(_QUERY_FROM_ABOVE_, Object[].class);
List<Object[]> results = q.getResultList();
// results.get(0)[0] -> Integer personId
// results.get(0)[1] -> String lastName
// results.get(0)[2] -> String firstName
// results.get(0)[3] -> Long COUNT
```

You may even ask for the entire `Person`, along with its count of phones:

```
SELECT p, (SELECT COUNT(ph) FROM p.phones ph)
WHERE ...
```

With code similar to the one above, `results.get(0)[0]` is the entire `Person` object, `results.get(0)[1]` is the count as `Long`.

Comment: or perhaps "tuples"

Comment: Thank you for the response. This solution works for static where clause.  In my scenario, the where clause is generated based on the filter passed in.

I found a solution to this issue by creating a view table with the counts.  From JPA, I can just run normal query findAll(spec, pageable) on the view table.